# Wordpress posts display only ????? characters after being saved. (unicode characters only)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, unicode, utf-8

Tried referencing all the other posts on this matter but no luck.

The issue that, there are posts in English, Tamil and Sinhala (native language of Sri Lanka). The english articles are fine. But for sinhala and tamil the characters show ????? ?? ??? after being saved or updated. What we do is we copy and paste from google translate and transliterate directly to the wordpress editor.

I have checked the mysql table and it also shows the ??? ??? characters. But when inserted directly into the DB using phpmyadmin the characters display fine. Both in phpmyadmmin as well as in wordpress. But once edited or updated it goes back to being ??? ????.

Wordpress char set is utf8 and collate is ''. Tried changing them to various settings and commenting out also but nothing worked so far.

Does anyone know the solution. We have the same setup on another test server and all the functions works on that server without any issue. Is there a specific PHP setting (btw, default charset in php ini is set to utf8) that is causing the problem?[image]

Comment: What is the `database character set` and the `collation` set in the `wp-config.php` file? The values to look for will be `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE`.

Comment: Another thing to consider is `WP` version. In older version (*upto 2.2 I believe*) the default DB charset/collation is in `latin`. So please also check for that too.

Comment: @HimelNagRana DB-CHARSET is utf8. DB-COLLATE is ' '. empty value. DB char set is utf8mb4_unicode_ci. wp version is the lastest 4.x.x. thank you for the reply. :D

Comment: Hi, thanks for informing. Can you please check by setting `DB_COLLATE` to `utf8_general_ci`? It should work. (y)

Comment: Hi, tried that. But no luck. Still upon update the ??? appear. But when inserted from phpmyadmin to the table directly it shows up correct

Comment: Inserting from `phpmyadmin` is not a real-life scenario. But it proves that `DB` settings is alright. Now you have to check when you are inserting from `WP` it works or not. I mean don't update the past posts - try to create new posts. And see @RickJames answer - he has broken down the things quite well.

Answer (score 0):

The CHARSET is important; the COLLATE is not (for this question).

This is *probably* what happened.

- You are `INSERTing` non-western-Europe text
- You said `SET NAMES utf8` to declare that the client bytes are utf8-encoded (correct).
- But the columns are declared `CHARSET latin1`.
- Since there is no way to convert Chinese characters into latin1, '?' stored.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can verify that the column is not `utf8`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The columns in question (post title, post content) are utf8. But some other columns on the wp-posts table are as your said latin. But the fact remains that whenever I insert the text directly into the table via phpmyadmin is shows up in the site, Only after saving it again (after updating the post) it goes back to being ???

Comment: Mixing WP and phpmyadmin?  Make sure everything connects using utf8.  Don't use user=root.